# How can I create log files on loop using mechanize with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I am trying to make more than one log file on localhost

one file is `sign_in.rb`

```
require 'mechanize'

@agent = Mechanize.new
page = @agent.get('http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in')
form =page.forms.first
form["user[username]"] ='admin'
form["user[password]"]= '123456'
@agent.submit(form,form.buttons.first)

pp page
```

the second is `profile_page.rb`

```
require 'mechanize'
require_relative 'sign_in'


page = @agent.get('http://localhost:3000/users/admin')
form =page.forms.first

form.radiobuttons_with(:name => 'read_permission_level')[1].check
@agent.submit(form,form.buttons.first)


pp page
```

how can I combine these two files and run them on loop in order to create more than one log file

Comment: This would be a better question if you told us what you tried and what errors you got when trying it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Mechanize, but is there any reason you can't simply combine the two bits of code and put them a while loop?  I don't know how often you need to do `Mechanize.new`.  To make more than one log file, simply open two different files and write to them.

```
require 'mechanize'
require_relative 'sign_in'

log1 = File.open("first.log", "w")
log2 = File.open("second.log", "w")

@agent = Mechanize.new
while true
    # @agent = Mechanize.new  # not sure if this is needed
    page = @agent.get('http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in')
    form = page.forms.first
    form["user[username]"] ='admin'
    form["user[password]"]= '123456'
    @agent.submit(form,form.buttons.first)
    PP.pp page, log1

    # @agent = Mechanize.new  # not sure if this is needed
    page = @agent.get('http://localhost:3000/users/admin')
    form = page.forms.first
    form.radiobuttons_with(:name => 'read_permission_level')[1].check
    @agent.submit(form,form.buttons.first)
    PP.pp page, log2
end
```

Comment: I have more than two files and I want to create a log file that will combine all the files and run on loop, is there a way to make the files into classes and call the classes in a files that combines them.. and thanks for the help ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you asking now.  What do you mean by "create a log file that will combine all the files and run on loop"?  A log file does not combine or run anything.  Log files are not executable.  Log files do not run or have loops.  Maybe you should ask a new question or edit this one heavily.